# How do I prove the parrallelogram law?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question asks to prove the parrallelogram law: for all ${\vec{u}},{\vec{v}} $ $\epsilon$ $\Bbb R^n $,  $\|{\vec{u}} +  {\vec{v}}\|^2$+$\|{\vec{u}} -  {\vec{v}}\|^2$ $   
=$  $2(\|{\vec{u}} \|^2 + \|{\vec{v}} \|^2)$

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding the left hand side and then factoring.

Answer (score 0):

Multilinearity of the inner product:
$$\lVert\vec u+\vec v\rVert^2=\langle\vec u+\vec v,\vec u+\vec v\rangle=\lVert\vec u\rVert^2+2\langle\vec u,\vec v\rangle+\lVert\vec v\rVert^2,$$ &c.